# Woocommerce products shortcode by product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble displaying woocommerce products of a specific category, using the Woocommerce products shortcode.

Using

```
[products category="red-wine"]
```

outputs all the products. I can't seem to find what I'm missing.

Comment: you could use the category id to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-7), you have to specify the `limit` parameter, which defaults to `-1` (all products) in case of category listings. So that would be

```
[products category="red-wine" limit="8"]
```

or whatever number of products you want.